# Hardware problem, graphic card cannot be initialized after 10.12.6 update

Tags: macos, gpu

I updated my iMac to 10.12.6. As soon as iMac restarted after the update was finished, the screen went off.

I tried to connect it from another mac using screen-share, and I was successful. I noticed that system is running normally except for the screen which is off. Using screen-share, I can access internet, connect bluetooth devices, print… etc, but the screen is off.

System report shows me **"No information found."** under **Graphic/Display**.

I can't run system restore, because screen never goes on during the boot cycle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Hardware Overview

- Model Name: iMac
- Model Identifier: iMac12,2
- Processor Name: Intel Core i5
- Processor Speed: 3.1 GHz
- Number of Processors: 1
- Total Number of Cores: 4
- L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
- L3 Cache: 6 MB
- Memory: 8 GB